# Inverting a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck with the following problem

I am supposed to find the inverse of the function $g$ with $2$ variables, where

$$\begin{align*}g&: R^2\to R^2 \\ g&(x,y)=(2ye^{2x}, xe^y)\end{align*}$$

I do not know even how to do it, the book does not give an example. Could you please tell me of a general method of how to invert this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you can find here the solution to your problem
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221148/how-do-we-find-the-inverse-of-a-function-with-2-variables

Comment: That did not help, I looked at that

Comment: The Jacobian is $(4xy-2)e^{2x+y}$ which vanishes on the ellipse $4xy=2$ so maybe there's a problem. (I think one needs nonzero Jacobian near a point for a local inverse there.)

Comment: that stuck me too. But can you please in general suggest a way of finding inverse of functions with 2 variable. Perhaps I can figure it out myself, I do not know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function $g(x,y)$ is not one-to-one, and so has no inverse. Each of the points $(1,1)$ and  $(a,b)$ map to the same ordered pair $(c,d)$ where (approximately) $a=2.61229...,\ b=0.039772...$ and the output ordered pair $(c,d)$ is about $c=14.77811, \ d=2.71828...$
So this means one cannot find $x,y$ uniquely for this particular pair $(c,d)$ so there can't be an inverse function giving each of $x,y$ as functions of the ordered pair of $g(x,y).$