# Multivariate inverse function

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

How do I find the inverse of the below using inverse mapping?

$X,Y$ are independent random variables.

$U = [x/(x+y)], V = [(x+y)]$

An example of a solution to another problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221148/how-do-we-find-the-inverse-of-a-function-with-2-variables). However, I do not understand how the inverse is made. The answer in that question bypasses the actual process of the mapping.

This is my incorrect solution:

Inverse of $U$:

1) $U = X/V$ Substituting V for the (x+y) term.

2) $X = U/V$ Swap U and X to create the inverse function

3) According to the process of solving inverses, you solve for X. It's already solved for X so no further work necessary.

The same process applies to $V$:

1) $V = (U/V)+Y$ Substituting U for V in the X term.

2) $Y = (U/V)+V$ Swap V with Y to create the inverse.

3) As before, a third step would apply if variable Y was not isolated, however it is and no further work is necessary as we have the inverse.

Comment: Your solution goes wrong when you state that "2) X=U/V" Actually, U=X/V in your 1) yields X=UV, not X=U/V. Later on, "1) V = (U/V)+Y Substituting U for V in the X term" continues the mistake. Actually, V=UV+Y.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse of U and V are:
 $$ X=UV$$
$$ Y=V(1-U)$$

Then, you have to calculate the Jacobian determinant of this inverse and evaluate the integral, in the domain determinated for U and V, of the pdf of X and Y calculated in the function inverse.

This is the 
[theorem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Invertible_Transformation_of_a_Random_Vector_.28n.3Dm.29).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that this is the correct inverse. What steps did you take to get from $U=[x/(x+y)]$ to $X = UV$? That is the primary point of my question. I'm trying to understand what was wrong with my method detailed in the question.