# How to get latitudinal tori using the inverse Hopf map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, inverse-function, hopf-fibration

We define the Hopf map as a function from $S^3$ into $S^2$, $f(z_1, z_2) = \frac{z_2}{z_1}$, where $S^3=\{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb C^2 | |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1\}$ and $S^2$ is the Reimann sphere $z=\frac{z_2}{z_1}$.

Now, we want to find the inverse map $f^{-1}(z)$, (in order to find the latitudinal tori later.)

$f: (z_1, z_2) \to z$

$f^{-1}: z \to (z_1, z_2)$

If [we use](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221148/how-do-we-find-the-inverse-of-a-function-with-2-variables) $z_1 = \frac{z_2}{z}$ and $z_2 = zz_1$, then we should be able to replace $z_1$ and $z_2$ to find the inverse map, and so we get $f^{-1}(z) = \frac{zz_1}{\frac{z_2}{z}} \Rightarrow f^{-1}(z) = z$, which helps little.

It is understandable that a function with two variables as input and one variable as output is so unlikely to be invertible. However, the input variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ are related since $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1$. Moreover, we will need an inverse Hopf map for showing that the tori $\sigma(f^{-1}(|z|=r))$ are tori of revolution. So there should be an algebraic way for getting an $S^1 \times S^1$ surface using the inverse Hopf map.

We know that in the Reimann sphere, $|z|=r$ defines a circle with the center point at the origin and radius $r$. On the other hand, by sending $z$ back to $\mathbb R^4$ using the inverse stereographic projection and applying $S^1$ action we can get a circle worth of unit quaternions in $S^3$. So, we have our $S^1 \times S^1$ in this way here, but how do they relate in an algebraic way to get a torus of revolution such that $(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + R^2 - r^2)^2 = 4R^2(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$, where $S^3=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb R^4 | x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 1\}$, $r=x_3^2 + x_4^2$ which is the smaller radius and $R=(x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2 \pm \sqrt {r^2 - x_3^2}$ which is the bigger radius.

Found $r$ starting from $z = \frac{z_2}{z_1}$ and using $|z| = r$, next, found $R$ starting from $(|z_1| + x_3^2 + R^2 - r^2)^2 = 4R^2|z_1|$ and using $r = |z_2|$.

Reference:

- Treisman, Z., a young person's guide to the Hopf fibration, exercise 4.7.,   (2009), [arXiv:0908.1205](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1205) [math.HO]
- The Hopf fibration [visual model](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/bttypjqd) using Geogebra 3D calculator

[image: latitudinal tori]

Comment: The Hopf map is definitely not invertible: its fibers are circles.

Answer (score 1):

> It is understandable that a function with two variables as input and one variable as output is so unlikely to be invertible. However, the input variables z1 and z2 are related since $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$.

Well, yes, but they're not *that* related. You can't solve for $z_2$ in terms of $z_1$, only its magnitude not its phase. Consider the real variables involved; the domain $S^3$ is three-dimensional and the range $S^2$ is two-dimensional and the Hopf map is continuous so you can expect (and by "invariance of domain" in topology) the function cannot be invertible.

> Moreover, we will need an inverse Hopf map for showing that the tori are tori of revolution.

That's not correct. The notation $f^{-1}$ here is being used for *inverse image* (rather than "image under inverse function"). The fiber of a point $z_1/z_2$ is the set $\{(e^{i\theta}z_1,e^{i\theta}z_2)\}$ which is indeed the orbit of $(z_1,z_2)$ under the action of $S^1$; the fibers are all circles. However, if you take a circle in $S^2$ and take the inverse image, you get a *circle of circles*, which is a torus. It turns out the fibers are "diagonal" Hopf circles in the torus, not your usual poloidal or toroidal circles.

Such a circle in the Riemann sphere $S^2$ we can say is $\{e^{i\phi}z\}$ so the inverse image will be the torus orbit $\{(uz_1,vz_2)\mid u,v\in S^1\}$ (this is an orbit of $S^1\times S^1$ acting on $S^3$ within $\mathbb{C}^2$). I'll let you verify under stereographic projection this is a torus of revolution.